# Navbar Irregularly Appearing and Disapearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timeout, fade

I have a code that is intended to make a navbar disappear when the mouse is still, and when the mouse moves, it is supposed to fade in. The code works, except that when the mouse is still, the navbar will fade out, but then will fade in a couple seconds later, and continue fading out and in at regular intervals. The website with the problem is [here](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/nationals_website/blinker.html).
**My code is below**

```
$("#header").hide();

$("html").mousemove(function( event ) {
$("#header").fadeIn(1500);

myStopFunction();
myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
myVar = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#header").fadeOut(1500);
}, 2000);
}
function myStopFunction() {
if(typeof myVar != 'undefined'){
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (pattern)

```
$(function () {
    var _toggle = function () {
        $(document).one("mousemove.t", function (e) {
            e.target = $("#header");
            $(e.target).toggle(1500).delay(2000).toggle(1500, function () {
                _toggle()
            })
        })
    };
    $.when(_toggle())
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8VeDN/

Comment: it works perfectly! except for one problem. The navbar disappears even when the mouse is moving, so I'll move the mouse and it will appear (perfect) but then it will disappear again a few seconds later. I need it to stay visible whenever the mouse is moving and only disappear if the mouse is still. Do you have a remedy. Otherwise, thank you!

Comment: oh and also, it makes the navbar appear diagonally from the top left corner. It would be great if it could appear just from the top down.

Comment: @etangins See updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8VeDN/ , adjusted timings, i.e., `toggle(500).delay(5000).toggle(500, function(){_toggle()})` . Not certain about `navbar`, `css` layout, `html` was not present at original post; from link, utilized what appear to be `html` portion indicated at original post, at jsfiddle, for original post requirement. Did not attempt any `css`, layout adjustments, just toggle effect. If possible, can create jsfiddle, or post another Question (perhaps, with `html`, `css`, `js` posted at original post) for `css` issue ? Thanks

Comment: I see the adjusted timings, but it still seems to fade even when the mouse is moving

Comment: @etangins If interpret requirement correctly, elements fade out when mouse does not move ? fade in, fade out, or `toggle` effect settings has timing, or `duration`. If mouse move immediately before end of duration, elements still toggle (fade out), then toggle again (fade in) due to `mousemove` `event` immediately before fade out. Tried to include 5 individual functions into single piece. An option to minimize overlap may be to reduce `toggle` `duration` further (`toggle(0).delay(5000).toggle(0)`); also include `$.fx.interval = 0` at top of piece, before `_toggle`. See updated jsfiddle. Thanks

Comment: What I essentially want is for the navbar to fadeout if and only if the mouse does not move and for the navbar to fadein if the mouse moves, and stay faded in while the mouse is still moving. Once the mouse stops moving, the navbar should fadeout and not fade in until the mouse moves again.

Comment: @etangins navbar begins displayed, or not displayed ? Duration until fade out if no mousemove ? Duration of fade in if mousemove ?

Comment: Navbar begins not displayed. 3 seconds until fadeout if no mousemove. 1 seconds duration of fade in if mousemouve.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52635/discussion-between-guest271314-and-etangins)

Comment: @etangins See , try updated jsfiddle (same link at post). Note, Does not provide 1 second `fadeIn`; `header` remains displayed while `mousemove, with perceptible, yet perhaps "minimal" "flicker" effect. Thanks